# Assigning max value of smaller integer to a larger integer

Tags: c++, integer, ones-complement

Consider the following code:

```
 uint32_t x = ~uint8_t(0);
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Now, I fully expected this to output `255`, but instead it output `4294967295`.

I'm aware of integer promotion in C++, but I can't understand why this would happen.  The way I understand it, the expression `~uint8_t(0)` should evaluate to `1111 1111` in binary.  The `~` operator will then cause the type to be promoted to an `int` (which I'll assume is 32-bit for the sake of discussion), by sign extending the value to `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111`.  This promoted value should then be assigned to the lvalue `x`, resulting in `x == 255`.

But obviously I'm not understanding this correctly.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral promotions are performed on the operand of the unary `~`, so the `uint8_t(0)` is promoted to `int` and then the `~` is evaluated.  It's equivalent to

```
~(int)(uint8_t)0
```

You can get the maximum value representable by a type using `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`; if the type is unsigned, you can also cast `-1` to that type:

```
uint32_t x = (uint8_t)-1;
```

Comment: Isn't it promoted to `int`, rather than `unsigned int`?

Comment: @Channel, you're right, because §4.5 (Integral promotions) "An rvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to an rvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source rvalue can be converted to an rvalue of type unsigned int."  An int can obviously hold any byte.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: That sounds like C99, not C++03.

Comment: @MSalters, no it's from a [2008 C++ working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf).  `cstdint`, which is used in both the question and answer, isn't available in C++03 (it is planned to be C++0x).  The fixed-with chars are only in C++ drafts so far (not any C).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the bitwise not operator (`~`) is promoting its operand to an `int` before it executes.  This is then converted to an `unsigned int` by the assignment.

Here are some related code samples that make this more clear:

```
uint8_t y = ~uint8_t(0);
uint32_t x = y;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

> 255

```
uint8_t y = uint8_t(0);
int z = ~y;
uint32_t x = z;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

> 4294967295